# Problems with JavaScript media queries and CSS animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, css-animations

I came across a minor issue on a website that I am working on, but that's breaking my head. I am using CSS animations and JavaScript media queries at the same time. The breaking point is 768px, and that triggers an event in which the second div is appended to the first one. Each div contains an animated element. The problem is that the animation of the appended element reboots when the function triggers (while the animation of the other element remains steady).

I would like to find a way in which the animation of the appended element don't reboot each time you cross the breakpoint. I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that appended childs "reappear" in the DOM causing the reboot of the animation. Bur I don't know how to fix this. Every bit of help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```js
//---Start of Square Color Animation---
function colorSquare1() {
  var square1Blue = document.getElementById("square-1");
  var square2Red = document.getElementById("square-2");

  if (square1Blue.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
    document.getElementById("square-1").classList.toggle("square-animation-red");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("square-1").classList.toggle("square-animation-blue");
  }
  if (square2Red.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
    document.getElementById("square-2").className = "square";
  }
}

function colorSquare2() {
  var square2Blue = document.getElementById("square-2");
  var square1Red = document.getElementById("square-1");

  if (square2Blue.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
    document.getElementById("square-2").classList.toggle("square-animation-red");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("square-2").classList.toggle("square-animation-blue");
  }
  if (square1Red.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
    document.getElementById("square-1").className = "square";
  }
}
//---End of Square Color Animation---
//---Start of Queries Animation---
function myFunction(x) {

  if (x.matches) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("container-1");
    var square2 = document.getElementById("square-container-2");

    mainContainer.appendChild(square2);

  } else {
    var square2 = document.getElementById("square-container-2");
    var secondContainer = document.getElementById("container-2");

    secondContainer.appendChild(square2);
  }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")
myFunction(x)
x.addListener(myFunction)

//---End of Queries Animation---
```

```css
#container {
  max-width: 72px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.square-animation-blue {
  animation-name: changeToBlue;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeToBlue {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.square-animation-red {
  animation-name: changeToRed;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes changeToRed {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container-1">
    <div id="square-container-1">
      <a href="#" id="square-1" class="square" onclick="colorSquare1()"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    <div id="square-container-2">
      <a href="#" id="square-2" class="square" onclick="colorSquare2()"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using animations you can use the CSS transition property.

```
.square-animation-blue{
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

CSS Transitions: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style type="text/css">
    #container{
        max-width: 72px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .square{
        width: 54px;
        height: 54px;
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .square-animation-blue{
        transition: background-color 0.5s;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .square-animation-red{
        transition: background-color 0.5s;
        background-color: red;
    }
    


</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
    <div id="container-1">      
        <div id="square-container-1">           
            <a href="#" id="square-1" class="square" 
             onclick="colorSquare1()"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container-2">
        <div id="square-container-2">
            <a href="#" id="square-2" class="square" 
             onclick="colorSquare2()"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     //---Start of Square Color Animation---
    function colorSquare1() {
        var square1Blue = document.getElementById("square-1");
        var square2Red = document.getElementById("square-2");

        if (square1Blue.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
            document.getElementById("square-1").classList.toggle("square-animation-red");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("square-1").classList.toggle("square-animation-blue");
        }
        if (square2Red.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
            document.getElementById("square-2").className = "square";
        }
    }

    function colorSquare2() {
        var square2Blue = document.getElementById("square-2");
        var square1Red = document.getElementById("square-1");

        if (square2Blue.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
            document.getElementById("square-2").classList.toggle("square-animation-red");
         } else {
            document.getElementById("square-2").classList.toggle("square-animation-blue");
        }
        if (square1Red.classList.contains("square-animation-blue")) {
            document.getElementById("square-1").className = "square";
        } 
    }
  //---End of Square Color Animation---
  //---Start of Queries Animation---
    function myFunction(x) {    
        if (x.matches) {
         console.log("moved to container 1"); 
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("container-1");
            var square2 = document.getElementById("square-container-2");

            mainContainer.appendChild(square2);

        } else {
            console.log("moved to container 2"); 
            var square2 = document.getElementById("square-container-2");
            var secondContainer= document.getElementById("container-2");

            secondContainer.appendChild(square2);
        }
    }

    var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)")
    myFunction(x)
    x.addListener(myFunction)

//---End of Queries Animation---    
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Trobol thank you very much. It works perfectly. Actually I have tried before the transfrorm property but I couldn't make it work. Thanks to your answer I found the proper way to use it, you have fixed my problem and there will be less lines of code in my project.